# How do you stop PDF hotlinking and automatically redirect hotlink clickers?

Tags: redirects

I have some PDF documents that I offer users once they have subscribed to my newsletter. Well, Google found them, and other people are posting them on various sites.

I'd like to take advantage of Google ranking my PDF documents and redirect users that click on those links to an HTML or PHP page.

How do you automatically redirect hotlinked PDF clicks (on Google search and other sites) to a relevant page (i.e. `example.com/PDFdoc1.pdf` redirects to `example.com/PDFdoc1.html` or `example.com/PDFdoc1/`)?

I want to keep the PDFs ranked where they are on Google, and keep the PDF documents exactly where they are on my site, but just redirect hotlinked clickers to a page instead of the PDF.

How can this be done?